# Ravel's "Sheherazade" by Boulez & von Otter; official title on side of cd

Tags: classical-music, cd, artwork

There is a Deutsche Grammophon CD with these compositions:

> Ravel: Sheherazade, Le Tombeau de Couperin, Pavane, Menuet Antique
> Debussy: Danses, Le Jet d'Eau, 3 Ballades de François Villon

by Pierre Boulez conducting The Cleveland Orchestra, with soloists Anne Sofie von Otter, Allison Hagley and Lisa Wellbaum (see e.g. on [discogs.com](https://www.discogs.com/Maurice-Ravel-Claude-Debussy-The-Cleveland-Orchestra-Pierre-Boulez-Sh%C3%A9h%C3%A9razade-Le-Tombeau-de-Coupe/release/8558663)).

As you can see below, the front cover of this CD has quite  lot of names and titles on it, but I'm trying to find out what the side of the CD case looks like. There's probably only place for something like "BOULEZ RAVEL DEBUSSY" or "BOULEZ VON OTTER SHEHERAZADE" and the DG logo and catalogue number. I'd also like to know whether the colours are the traditional white with black title and yellow with black catalogue number.

This may seem like a strange request, but I'll be visiting someone soon, and I want to check whether they already have this cd, and I may only have a minute to look at their CD collection, so I'd like to be able to recognize it as quickly as possible, and I haven't been able to find an image of it online.

[image: Boulez, von Otter, Ravel, Sheherazade, CD booklet]

Comment: Note that this CD is also part of [that 44 CD box set](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00P08LJ1Q), and probably part of [this compilation](https://www.deutschegrammophon.com/en/catalogue/products/boulez-ravel-debussy-5171) (among others), either of which your friend may own.

Answer (score 1):

I did not manage to find something either, some other information may be found on [DG](https://www.deutschegrammophon.com/de/katalog/produkte/ravel-debussy-von-otter-hagley-boulez-7788). Given the additional problems of

- where to sort in a multi-composer CD like this and
- the habit of record labels, to re-issue, currently seeming to favor big boxes with more than 10 CDs, I'm afraid you will not have much more than the somewhat characteristic yellow, Deutsche Grammophon has also in its label.

I provide an example here (from a CD appearing the year before, which also the small label in the upper left on the booklet title), but unfortunately it can't be relied on depending on the series:

[image: example Deutsche Grammophon backside]